# boost::variant and moveconstructible

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

boost::variant 1.57 spec says that:

> The requirements on a bounded type are as follows:
>   CopyConstructible or MoveConstructible.

but below code does not compile on MSVC2012.

```
#include <boost\variant.hpp>

struct A
{
    A(){}
    A(A&& other){}

    A operator=(A&& other){return *this;}

private:
    A(A const & other){} // MSVC2012 does not support deleted
};

int main() 
{
    boost::variant<A> testVariant;

    testVariant = A();
}
```

> error C2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'

Is it because of lack of proper support for C++11 in MSVC2012 compiler, or is it a boost::variant bug?

If it's problem with MSVC2012, than do you know any workarounds?

**UPDATE**

In my short example there was move assignement operator missing. I updated the example.

Adding throw() to the default constructor fixed the problem. Previously I tried to add throw() to the move constructor and move operator, but that did not work. Thanks sehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you need the move-assignment as well.

And make the default constructor noexcept:

```
struct A
{
    A() noexcept {}
    A(A&&) {}
    A& operator=(A&&) {}

private:
    A(A const&){} // MSVC2012 does not support deleted
};
```

If MSVC2012 doesn't support `noexcept` (I believe it doesn't) you can try `throw()` (or maybe Boost gracefully allows it)

Comment: adding throw() to default constructor fixed my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
testVariant = A();
```

It's call to move assignment operator, since variant is already created.

```
boost::variant<A> testVariant = A();
```

This line should work as you expect.

Your code compiles with clang and gcc if move assignment operator is defined and move or default constructor is declared with `noexcept`.